# Inability to change string

Tags: python, string, immutability

I am trying to solve a maze question.

```
maze = [
"#o######",
"# ##   #",
"# ## # #",
"#    # #",
"## ### #",
"##  ## #",
"######e#",
]

maze[0][1] = "#"
```

Output:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I thought of an algorithm that works with the logic of filling the space behind me with a "#" every time I move forward. But I learned that strings are immutable.

Is there anything in Python that allows me to run this algorithm in another way?

Comment: Strings are immutable in python. Try making each of the items of maze `lists`, for example. (This is easy with `maze = [list(i) for i in maze]` if you don't want to type it out.)

Answer (score 1):

You can only access specific char from string using its index, but you cannot change it. You have to recreate it, eg. to change first digit of string:

```py
text = 'abcdef'
text = 'X' + text[1:] # changes first letter to X and adds rest of the string
> 'Xbcdef'
```

Or more general example:

```py
def change(text, char, index):
    return text[:index] + char + text[(index+1):]

text = 'abcdef'
text = change(text, 'X', 2)
> 'abXdef'
```

So i your maze case:

```py
maze = [
"#o######",
"# ##   #",
"# ## # #",
"#    # #",
"## ### #",
"##  ## #",
"######e#",
]

maze[0] = change(maze[0], '#', 1)
```

Comment: However, changing anything other than the first or last gets a bit convoluted.

Comment: @S3DEV no it doesn't, check out my latest edit

Answer (score 1):

You can change the list of strings to a list of lists by doing

```
maze = [list(s) for s in maze] #list comprehension
```

or more verbosely

```
for i in range(len(maze)):
    maze[i] = list(maze[i])
```

Then you can do things like `maze[0][1] = "#"`.

If you want it back in string form, do

```
maze = ["".join(lst) for lst in maze]
```

or

```
for i in range(len(maze)):
    maze[i] = "".join(maze[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` method instead.

```
maze = [
"#o######",
"# ##   #",
"# ## # #",
"#    # #",
"## ### #",
"##  ## #",
"######e#",
]
for i in maze:
    j = i.replace("o","#")
    print(j)
```